# Как проверить что все элементы массива равны друг другу?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив:

```
var arr = [5, 5, 5, 5];
```

Как проверить что все элементы массива равны друг другу "одинаковые"?

Comment: вот здесь - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array - функция возвращающая массив уникальных элементов

Comment: Вариант с lodash: `_.uniq(arr).length === 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В динамическом `JS` довольно размыто понятие 'одинаковы'.

```js
/**
 * Сравнивает содержимое массива на... одинаковость
 *
 * @param {Array}   arr    Массив для проверки
 * @param {Boolean} strict Уровень проверки, дефолтно (false) - строгий (5 НЕ равно '5');
 *                         Если true - без проверки типов (5 БУДЕТ равно '5')
 *
 * @throws {Error} Если первый аргумент не является массивом, кидается ошибка
 *
 * @return {Boolean} Результаты проверки
 */
function compareArr(arr, strict){
  let test,
      equal = strict ? (a, b) => a == b : (a, b) => a === b;
  
  if(!Array.isArray(arr))
    throw new Error(`It is not an array!`);
  
  try{
    arr.reduce(
      (prev, current) => {
        if(equal(current, prev))
          return current;
        else
          throw new Error(1);
    });
    
    test = true;
  }catch(e){
    test = false;
  }
  
  return test;
}

// Tests:

console.info(compareArr([5,5,5,5,5]));   // True
console.info(compareArr([5,5,'5',5,5])); // False

console.info(compareArr([5,5,5,5,5], true));   // True
console.info(compareArr([5,5,'5',5,5], true)); // True
```

Comment: Интуитивно, если параметр `strict` равен `true`, ожидается более строгое сравнение (в вашем коде наоборот получается).

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, мне как-то так удобнее и понятнее. Хотя поменять, если нужно, можно быстро.

Comment: с массивом `[NaN,NaN]` - не работает

Comment: @Grundy, а ещё с массивом объектов и потомков объекта. То, что дали в задании - корректно обрабатывает. Что-то большее... я сегодня брился и посчитал верным решение без лишнего кода. Да и ТС вроде доволен, раз ответ принят.

Answer (score 4):

варианты...

```js
 var arr = [5, 5, 5, 5],
   ar = [5, 5, 5, "5"];

 function foo(a) {
   for (var b = 0; b < a.length; b++)
     if (a[b] !== a[0]) return !1;
   return !0
 };

 alert([foo(arr), foo(ar)]);
```

```js
 var arr = [5, 5, 5, 5],
   ar = [5, 5, 5, "5"];

 function foo(a) {
   return !a.some(function(b) {
     return b !== a[0]
   })
 };

 alert([foo(arr), foo(ar)]);
```

```js
 var arr = [5, 5, 5, 5],
   ar = [5, 5, 5, "5"];

 function foo(a) {
   return [...new Set(a)].length == 1

 };

 alert([foo(arr), foo(ar)]);
```